# Linux IPVS in DR mode on vyos router/firewall not forwarding reply packets

Tags: linux-networking, lvs, ipvs, vyos

I am setting up setup where:

1. I use vyos as router/firewall
2. on vyos i setup also IPVS in DR mode. It means that IPVS changes request packet MAC-address to realserver MAC-address and forwards packet with original SRC/DST IP-s to realserver.
3. realserver recieves packet and replys directly to clients IP-address. For that realserver has also VIP address on loopback(arp packets are disabled). Realserver conf should be OK because reply's are going to vyos.
4. as vyos is on the path between realservers and clients and acts also as router then reply packet should be routed through vyos but should not be handled be IPVS anymore, just routed through vyos.

I am aware that this is not most standard solution and in most cases IPVS is separated from router/firewall to different host and IPVS host does not see in DR mode replay packets at all. But in my case I try to integrate IPVS functionality into vyos router/firewall.

Problem is that in vyos i see syn-ack reply packets in vyos realservers interface but they are not forwarded to clients interface.

Vyos interfaces:

```
vyos@vyos-1:~$ show interfaces 
Codes: S - State, L - Link, u - Up, D - Down, A - Admin Down
Interface        IP Address                        S/L  Description
---------        ----------                        ---  -----------
dum3             10.10.100.3/32                    u/u  IPVS-VIP
eth0             10.10.10.1/24                     u/u  IPVS-realservers
eth2             10.10.5.1/24                      u/u  client
lo               127.0.0.1/8                       u/u  
                 ::1/128
```

IPVS on vyos:

```
root@vyos-1:/home/vyos# ipvsadm -Ln
IP Virtual Server version 1.2.1 (size=4096)
Prot LocalAddress:Port Scheduler Flags
  -> RemoteAddress:Port           Forward Weight ActiveConn InActConn
TCP  10.10.100.3:80 sh
  -> 10.10.10.10:80               Route   1      0          0         
  -> 10.10.10.20:80               Route   1      0          0
```

RP filter is disabled

```
root@vyos-1:/home/vyos# sysctl -a | grep \\.rp_filter
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.dum3.rp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.rp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eth1.rp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eth2.rp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.rp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.pim6reg.rp_filter = 0
```

Testing from client(10.10.5.5) with curl:

```
curl http://10.10.100.3
```

tcpdump in vyos

```
root@vyos-1:/home/vyos# tcpdump -nnn -i any port 80
tcpdump: data link type LINUX_SLL2
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL2 (Linux cooked v2), snapshot length 262144 bytes
//Request packet from client to IPVS VIP on eth2
19:08:13.582552 eth2  In  IP 10.10.5.5.34200 > 10.10.100.3.80: Flags [S], seq 4055297170, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2156865110 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
//Request packet from IPVS to realserver on eth0
19:08:13.582708 eth0  Out IP 10.10.5.5.34200 > 10.10.100.3.80: Flags [S], seq 4055297170, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2156865110 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
//Reply packet from realserver to client on eth0
19:08:13.583239 eth0  In  IP 10.10.100.3.80 > 10.10.5.5.34200: Flags [S.], seq 2282149395, ack 4055297171, win 65160, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1876404975 ecr 2156865110,nop,wscale 7], length 0
//Previous reply packet is not forwarded to client interface eth2 
//Retry packets from client because client did not get reply: 
19:08:14.582700 eth2  In  IP 10.10.5.5.34200 > 10.10.100.3.80: Flags [S], seq 4055297170, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2156866111 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
19:08:14.582851 eth0  Out IP 10.10.5.5.34200 > 10.10.100.3.80: Flags [S], seq 4055297170, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2156866111 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
19:08:14.583211 eth0  In  IP 10.10.100.3.80 > 10.10.5.5.34200: Flags [S.], seq 2282149395, ack 4055297171, win 65160, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1876405975 ecr 2156865110,nop,wscale 7], length 0
19:08:15.604264 eth0  In  IP 10.10.100.3.80 > 10.10.5.5.34200: Flags [S.], seq 2282149395, ack 4055297171, win 65160, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1876406996 ecr 2156865110,nop,wscale 7], length 0
19:08:16.598753 eth2  In  IP 10.10.5.5.34200 > 10.10.100.3.80: Flags [S], seq 4055297170, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2156868127 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
19:08:16.598902 eth0  Out IP 10.10.5.5.34200 > 10.10.100.3.80: Flags [S], seq 4055297170, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2156868127 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
19:08:16.599546 eth0  In  IP 10.10.100.3.80 > 10.10.5.5.34200: Flags [S.], seq 2282149395, ack 4055297171, win 65160, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1876407991 ecr 2156865110,nop,wscale 7], length 0
19:08:18.612826 eth0  In  IP 10.10.100.3.80 > 10.10.5.5.34200: Flags [S.], seq 2282149395, ack 4055297171, win 65160, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1876410004 ecr 2156865110,nop,wscale 7], length 0
```

From firewall perspective there are no deny rules. Replay packet is seen/logged in PREROUTING chain but not in FORWARD chain.
I suspect that issue may be in case that replay packet source IP(10.10.100.3) is also in vyos dummy interface and thats why vyos thinks this should be locally routed packet or something... and is not forwarded to FORWARDING chain.

Any suggestions why reply packet is not forwarded in vyos and how to get it work?